# os.system() don't let updating image source in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to update the image source on a changeImageSource function it changes the source instantly but when I use time.sleep() method in that function, function executes but doesn't update the source of the image. updates after time.sleep() call completed.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import time
# creating the App class


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
    
        #creating and adding image to widget
        self.img = AsyncImage(
        source='http://kivy.org/logos/kivy-logo-black-64.png')
        self.img.pos = (400,400)
    
        #creating btn and adding press handler
        self.change_img_btn = Button(text="Change Image ")
        self.change_img_btn.bind(on_press = self.changeImageSource)
    
    
        #adding widget to Widget instance
        parent.add_widget(self.img)
        parent.add_widget(self.change_img_btn)
        return parent;

     def changeImageSource(self,*args):
        self.img.source = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"
        time.sleep(4)
    

# run the App
MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: You shouldn't ever use `sleep` inside GUI apps since it will make the interface unresponsive. Sleep in a seperate thread

Comment: `time.sleep` blocks the main thread. Try using another [**`Clock`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#module-kivy.clock) or another `thread`.

Comment: Thanks, that works but in my project there is os.system("mpg21 audio.mp3") instead of time.sleep() is there any alternative for that?

Comment: Thank you very much @ApuCoder I solved this using the Thread module

Answer (score 0):

One: The "return parent;" should be "return parent"
Two: Why do you need time.sleep()?

You can also try flipping line 29 and 30.